# Transfer data to NAS synology from server located behind a VPN

Tags: ssh, vpn, openvpn, nas, synology

Is it possible to configure a synology NAS to be able to transfer data (using ssh but other protocl are possible) from a server located behind a VPN. I've all the credentials to connect to the VPN and the server behind?

Thank you

```
           |
           |
Server A  --->  NAS
           |
           |
          VPN
```

Comment: Probably yes. What kind of VPN does the Synology need to connect to?

Comment: no idea.. How can I know that

Comment: How would you connect to that VPN from a regular PC?

Comment: I think it's openvpn